# Регулярные выражения. Произвольные символы в кавычках

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Необходимо из формата mxl (выгрузка 1С) выдернуть значения, заключённые в кавычки. Усложняется тем, что внутри могут быть точки и дополнительные кавычки. Часть строки:

```
{1,1,
{"#","4670003285177"}
}
},2,
{16,0,
{1,1,
{"#","             "}
}
},3,
{16,0,
{1,1,
{"#","Набор: вилка дерев., нож дерев., салфетка, стакан бум., тарелка бум. 205 мм по 4шт. ""Ностальгия"""}
```

Comment: т.е., вам нужны только `4670003285177` и `Набор: вилка дерев., нож дерев., салфетка, стакан бум., тарелка бум. 205 мм по 4шт. ""Ностальгия""` ?

Comment: @Эдуард да, они и `#` тоже.

Comment: формат подразумевает под собой некоторые правила кодирования. приведите полную строку, возможно, этот ваш формат можно легко преобразовать, к примеру, в json. Или использовать другие средства для работы с ним

Comment: а так, у вас вложенные кавычки экранируются еще одной кавычкой. проще всего заменить двойную кавычку на какой нить символ/подстроку. обработать регулярками, и вернуть замену к одинарной кавычке.

Comment: @НиколайПерепеленко посмотрите этот [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9826c3bebdd97596e33dcc34970ba39480bfd2b)

Comment: @teran не хотелось бы приводить 4-мегабайтную выгрузку из 1С клиента. Простых способов конвертации не нашёл. Есть ПО для этих целей, но конвертировать руками не вариант. За идею с кавычками спасибо, нужно попробовать.

Comment: @Эдуард в примере возвращается `"#","4670003285177"`, нужно две отдельных `"#"` и `"4670003285177"`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно искать соответствия внутри кавычек, а потом обрабатывать найденные подстроки:

```
$str = '{1,1,
{"#","4670003285177"}
}
},2,
{16,0,
{1,1,
{"#","             "}
}
},3,
{16,0,
{1,1,
{"#","Набор: вилка дерев., нож дерев., салфетка, стакан бум., тарелка бум. 205 мм по 4шт. ""Ностальгия"""}';

preg_replace_callback(
    '~"((?!\s{2,}).+?(?:".+")*)"~',
    function($m)use(&$arr) {
        $arr[] = preg_match('~","~', $m[1]) ? explode('","', $m[1])[1] : $m[1];
    },
    $str
);

print_r($arr);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #
    [1] => 4670003285177
    [2] => #
    [3] => Набор: вилка дерев., нож дерев., салфетка, стакан бум., тарелка бум. 205 мм по 4шт. ""Ностальгия""
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Регуляркой: нет кавычки слева, затем точно идёт кавычка, затем непустой набор символов состоящих ИЛИ из не-кавычек ИЛИ из двойных, затем закрывающая кавычка и следом кавычки быть не должно.

```
(?<!")"(?<in>([^"]+|"")+)"(?!")
```

Comment: на деле выглядит так https://regex101.com/r/vuNgNV/1